# How to convince Scala IDE to recognize org.apache.spark.graphx._ package?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-graphx

When I try to include GraphX into my work, it seems I'm doing something wrong because Scala IDE doesn't recognize `org.apache.spark.graphx._` or anything related to graphs (!)

Did I miss something when I first created my project? Do I need to include additional libraries (how?)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the GraphX dependency to your pom file.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark-graphx_2.10</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I have few more questions please! One: I've used this remote archetype catalogue from a book to create my maven project (https://github.com/spark-in-action/scala-archetype-sparkinaction/raw/master/archetype-catalog.xml). Does Scala IDE or Spark provide their own standard catalogue that I can safely use (instead of the above) to properly create my maven projects? Two: how can I change the log level inside the IDE's console? I used sc.setLogLevel("ERROR") but it still shows me INFO and WARN !

Comment: I recommend managing dependencies manually. Start off with `spark-core` and `spark-graphx` and add additional libraries as needed.

Comment: Try `import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.Level; Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR)`

Answer (score 0):

There is now a `--packages` option for the Spark shell. You use it like this:

```
spark-shell --packages [maven:coordinates:here]
```